# .htaccess RewriteRule performance (large amount of RegEx)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following .htaccess rules to rewrite multiple urls on my website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^privacy(\w|\s|\+|-|&|;|#)+policy/?$ index.php?page=privacy [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)(.*)+foo(\w|\s|\+|-|&|;|#)+bar/?$   index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

The first rule works efficiently for the "privacy policy" page.

The second rule, however, results in a noticeably poor server response time. I believe the way this rule is written causes a delay in querying my database for the ([A-Za-z]+) expression. There is a large amount of RegEx that apply to this rule, and some of the urls contain "extra" words after the RegEx. For example:

```
www.example.com/North+America+Foo+Bar/
```

queries the database for "North" to rewrite the url to

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=North
```

This is the reason why I included (.*) in the rule, but I fear this is the culprit of the slow response time. Complicated, I know.

Any ideas or suggestions to improve this rule for faster performance? I would prefer keeping the www.example.com/Expression+Foo+Bar/ format because hundreds of urls are already indexed by search engines. =/

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: ^([A-Za-z]+).*foo[\w\s\+-&;#]+bar/?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match the whole URI in 2nd rule. Try this rule with simplified regex:

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(?=.*?foo.*?bar) index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Outstanding. This greatly improved the response time. Thank you.